# Croatia & Bosnia-Herzegovina Border between Split - Dubrovnik

Tags: croatia, bosnia

I am planning on visiting Croatia this end of October, I haven't buy any tickets yet, as I still do some research.

Zagreb, Plitvice, Split and Dubrovnik are 4 cities/park I'd like to visit during my trip, and I am a bit worried on Split - Dubrovnik Itinerary. As I can see on the map, There's a clear Croatia/Bosnia-Herzegovina Border between those two cities and I might be traveling by bus.

I am not EU citizen but I have PR of Hungary, therefore I have no worry on Croatia as informed through this website: http://www.mvep.hr/en/consular-information/visas/visa-requirements-overview/

Please help on Bosnia-Herzegovina, I might need this information, since it's still unclear for me.

Answer (score 6):

This is exactly the concern I had this past summer (July 2015). There is a bus that goes through that part of Bosnia-Hezergovina, but that involves border crossings that I decided to avoid given that there does not seem to be anything particularly interesting in that area.

The choice we made and we're happy with it to simply go around. There is catamaran that goes from Dubrovnik to Split with a few stops along the way. You can take [the journey in one go for until October 31](http://www.korculainfo.com/ferries/ferry-split-milna-hvar-korcula-dubrovnik.html) but we took it in two parts stopping in Korcula which is really nice a historic. Some friends did the same the week after but stopped in Hvar instead which has a different vibe. The total trip takes about 6 hours on the water.

Should you choose to go by bus, there are 12 buses each day that take 4 to 5 hours. We took buses in other parts of Croatia and were quite happy with the service.

Comment: Hey @Itai, thank you for the recommendation. I think I'd like to avoid the border as well, as I still have unclear information on Bosnia-Herzegovina.

Comment: Don't worry about the 6 hours: some boats leave very early in the morning, allowing you to have more time at your destination. A good site to check all public transport is: https://www.putovnica.net/en/transport/ferry-transport

Answer (score 5):

**Update as of 2024:**

The **[Pelješac Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pelje%C5%A1ac_Bridge)** (opened in 2022, usable by buses since 2023) eliminates all problems arising from crossing through Bosnian territory (the [Neum corridor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neum)) in order to reach Dubrovnik from the rest of Croatia.

Bosnian borders with Croatia have always been open and the border crossing formalities are not too time consuming, but having to pass through Bosnia and Herzegovina is a major problem for those who need a Bosnian visa or (even worse) have a single-entry Schengen Area visa.

For other people, travelling through this tiny bit of Bosnia is nothing to be afraid of. It could be an interesting addition to one's itinerary and an opportunity to buy cheaper fuel.